# Use string as parameter for FilterExpression in dynamoDB query

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following string in python :

```
fe = "Attr('COLOR').eq('RED')"
```

and I'm trying to use `FilterExpression` to query a dynamoDB table, this is what I'm calling:

```
response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('key').eq(key),
                       FilterExpression=fe        
)
```

but I'm getting:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: "'", near: "('COLOR"
```

Is it possible to pass a string as a parameter for the `FilterExpression` query? It needs to come in as a string cause it's being fed by a dictionary. I tried stripping the quotes such as:

```
response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('key').eq(key),
                           FilterExpression=fe.replace('"', '')        
    )
```

but it hasn't worked. Any ideas as to what I might try next? Thanks!

Comment: Can you use `eval()`?  `FilterExpression=eval(fe)` seems to work.

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks so much. Want to write it as the answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can pass a string for the `FilterExpression`, but you can obtain the Python expression you want using `eval()`.

```
fe = "Attr('COLOR').eq('RED')"
key = 'myKey'
response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('key').eq(key),
                       FilterExpression=eval(fe))
```

Of course, you need to *really* trust your input when using `eval()`.